# To sum series of indexes

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, sum

I have a series of indexes in a dataframe s, which ranges from different states in a series of 0-9.
Here is a snapshot of the dataframe.

[image]

How can we sum the series in such a way that it contains sum of all series for a single state.

```
Eg- (MD,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)-    The sum of its all individual values

    (NJ, 0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)-  The sum of its all individual values
```

Comment: You can iterate over the rows, strip them and then check for index 0 (if MD or NJ) group them and add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your  DataFrame is `dt` and that your index is made by tuples:

```
dt.groupby([x[0] for x in dt.index])[["0"]].sum()
```